# Setting route attribute prevent the default route(Controller/Action)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

If I set route attribute on my action as mentioned below.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [Route("Login")]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {

    }
}
```

My default route is not working that is `/Account/Login`

I want both url should work

1. /Login
2. /Account/Login

Comment: Please post your entire route configuration. Some route is probably matching your `/Account/Login` URL before it reaches the default route, but without seeing the configuration it is not possible to tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now i get what you want. In your `RouteConfig.cs` (**App_Start** folder) you have:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

You should just add another route **AFTER** default:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        //this is your additional route
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Login",
            url: "Login",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login"}
        );
    }
```

Delete your `Route` attribute above `Login` method. Now you will be able to call your method with both urls.

**Alternative** after your comment. Change your controller like this:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return Login();
    }

    [Route("Login")]
    public ActionResult Login2()
    {
        return Login();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wants to keep RouteAttribute